# Modify Checkboxes based on changes in Streamlit

Tags: python, checkbox, callback, session-state, streamlit

I wanted to create a checkbox which checks all other checkboxes if checked and if the checkbox is unchecked that all other checkboxes also get unchecked.

For example:

[image]

Clicking on “all” should be also checking “option1, option2, etc.”. Same if I uncheck.

I tried to use session_states but could not come up with a solution.
Is there a possibility to modify checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this way.

```py
import streamlit as st 


isall = st.checkbox(label="All")

st.checkbox(label="option1", value=isall)
st.checkbox(label="option2", value=isall)
```